# How to manage artifactory / maven artifact using different profiles

Tags: maven, maven-3, artifactory, maven-profiles

i have some problems understanding how to manage different "jar" files generated using different profiles. 
An example. I have a project : *my.project:sample:1.0*
And we use two profiles:

1. Using ***Profile1*** is compiling using java 7 and with dependency *other:project:1.0*
2. Using ***Profile2*** is compiling using java 6 and with dependency *different:project:3.0*

Using command line in local environment is easy to manage, but I don't know how to store and manage it on artifactory.

We have two different projects that use the same library but generated using different profiles:

1. A Project require  *my.project:sample:1.0* - ***Profile1***"
2. Another project require  *my.project:sample:1.0* - ***Profile2***"

How can I specify those depedency with the library and the profile?

Clarification: The generated Jar it's storing using artifactory, and the projects resolve the dependencies using the repository. I can't use the project as a module.

Comment: What version of artifactory are you using?  I'm running into issues with this bug https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-5974 and I suspect we need to upgrade.

Comment: We have 2.6.5 installed, but we have 15 allowed snapshots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use classifier to make the distinction between artifacts and reuse the classifier in the dependency.

**defining a classifier**

To do so you need to define the classifier in maven-jar-plugin:

```
<profiles>
     <profile>
         <id>profile1</id>
         ...
         <build>
             <plugins>
                 <plugin>
                     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                     <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                     <version>2.4</version>
                     <executions>
                       <execution>
                       <phase>package</phase>
                       <goals>
                         <goal>jar</goal>
                       </goals>
                       <configuration>
                          <classifier>jdk6</classifier>
                       </configuration>
                      </execution>
                     </executions>
                 <plugin>
             <plugins>
         </build>
     </profile>
     <profile>
         <id>profile2</id>
         ...
         <build>
             <plugins>
                 <plugin>
                     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                     <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                     <version>2.4</version>
                     <executions>
                       <execution>
                       <phase>package</phase>
                       <goals>
                         <goal>jar</goal>
                       </goals>
                       <configuration>
                          <classifier>jdk7</classifier>
                       </configuration>
                      </execution>
                     </executions>
                 <plugin>
             <plugins>
         </build>
     </profile>
</profiles>
```

**using the classifier in dependency**

Very simple:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>myArtifact</artifactId>
    <classifier>jdk6</classifier>
<dependency>
```