# Hybrid JDK 1.7 Server 1.6 Client Maven Build of Artifacts

Tags: maven, java-7

I have a Maven project with both server back-end modules and client front-end modules.  The goal is to take advantage of performance improvements in JDK 7 for the server back-end modules but build the client modules in JDK 6 only.  The client modules run in Tomcat while the server modules are separate Java applications.

I am aware of the Maven configuration to target specific JDK:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
          <compilerVersion>1.6</compilerVersion>
          <fork>true</fork>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

One caveat to this approach is that there are common modules that are used by both the server modules and client modules necessitating two different binaries (JDK 6 and 7) for each module.

How can one compile one set of artifacts for a JDK 6, and another set of artifacts for JDK 7, and a third set of artifacts (used by both) for both JDK 6 and 7 all belonging to the same project?  Would it be necessary to divide the modules up into three separate projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you <target> 1.6, the resulting Jar will work perfectly fine in 1.6 and 1.7. No need to compile twice.

There is no perfo benefit (except perhaps in some very obscure cases) from using the 1.7 compiler or targetting 1.7 byte code. All the perfo lives in the JVM. Just make your common code be target 1.6. Unless you yourself can measure a speed advantage of compiling for 1.7, don't bother.

Comment: Good point, but wouldn't this sacrifice the performance benefits of 1.7?  I suppose I can live with server modules using shared modules compiled in 1.6 if I had no other option.  Ideally I want all server modules and dependencies to benefit from JDK 1.7 and all client modules and dependencies using JDK 1.6.

Comment: After your edit: I will go ahead and try what you suggest immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of bmargulies is very pertinent.

Anyway, if you really want to build different versions of some module (1.6 and 1.7) I suggest you to use 2 profiles, profile1 targeting jdk6, profile2 targeting jdk7. So both profiles will redefine the maven-compiler-plugin.

Both profiles can also redefine the maven-jar-plugin with a different classifier so that each module will be available in 2 versions (and use the classifier in your dependencies so that client use jdk6 and server use jdk7).

Here is another question with more details about the way you can do this: [How to manage artifactory / maven artifact using different profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433238/how-to-manage-artifactory-maven-artifact-using-different-profiles/15434523#15434523)

Comment: Thanks for posting, this is what I suspected despite some discouragement from using classifiers and profiles for this task.  Nevertheless, validating.